# Server-side move between NFS shares

Tags: mount, nfs, bind

I have these folders on my server:

```
/share1
/home/user
```

Both are actually on the same partition.
Now I want to be able to move files between these two folders directly on the server (without any data being transferred to client).

I had good working setup using Samba and symlinks, but for performance reasons I switched to NFS.

Now symlinks obviously do not work anymore so I used `mount --bind`:

```
mount --bind /share1 /home/user/share1
```

I now realized that `mount --bind` creates filesystem boundary so that neither NFS nor Samba can perform server-side move anymore.

Is there a way to avoid this (e.g. some mount option)?

Or is there a way how to create multiple NFS exports from one partition and still be able to perform server-side move on the client?

Comment: are you able to cp but not mv?

Comment: @Raza It does not actually matter. When copying or moving accross the "bound folder" boundary, data are routed via client computer - i.e. not directly. Using Samba, NFS, Windows or Linux clients. I am quite sure that it is how "mount --bind" normally works. But how to work around?